# putting 1 input into 2 mysql databases

Tags: php, mysql

I am wondering if it is possible to put the content of 1 input field of a register form into 2 different tables (ie email address into login and user_account tables) - Here is the question updated.

Comment: the way you use the word databases, seems like you are referring to tables

Comment: Sure, why not? Please provide more details on your question

Comment: I am creating a table called login which stores email, password, secret question and answer and also creating an account table which has title, name, address, town, email, telephone (off course both will have an ID) - The information would be inputted from a register form.

Comment: seems like it is really not different database, please refine your question so we can help you

Comment: You simply have to execute two seperate queries.

Answer (score 3):

simple stuff:

```
$conn1 = "database1"; //your first database connection
$conn2 = "database"; //your second database connection

$email =  mysqli_real_escape_string($conn1, $_POST['email']);    

$query = "INSERT INTO table (email) VALUES ($email)";

$run1 = mysqli_query($conn1 , $query);
$run2 = mysqli_query($conn2 , $query);
```

EDIT:
after reading the comments, its not 2 database's you are connecting to, its just one, using multiple tables. So:

```
$conn = //database connection

$email = $_POST['email'];

$query = "INSERT INTO table (email) VALUES ($email)";
$query2 = "INSERT INTO table2 (email) VALUES ($email);

$run = mysqli_query($conn , $query);
$run = mysqli_query($conn , $query2);
```

Comment: yes sorry you are correct i should have said tables and not databases.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can manage it easily by simply doing two statement in your php scripy.
Next time, add codes you have try so we can answer more specifically to your question.

Comment: I hadnt tryed anything as i was creating the fields in MySQL when i had asked the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) in order to update automatically the second table when the first is updated.
For example, if you want to copy each value of the *email* field in *login* table, into the *user_accounts* table, you can use this mysql command:

```
 CREATE TRIGGER `duplicate_insert` 
    AFTER INSERT ON `login` 
    FOR EACH ROW 
        INSERT IGNORE INTO user_accounts(email) 
        VALUES (NEW.email)
```

Therefore, each time you insert a new record in *login.email* field, it will be also inserted into the *user_accounts.email* field.
Anyway, this solution creates a redundancy, so you should use it if you want to keep a backup of your data or if you are handling very important information.

Otherwise, consider to use a [foreign key](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp).